# Can't install Xcode; issue with MobileDevice.pkg

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.6

I'm trying to install Xcode 4.6.2 in an admin account on OS X 10.7.5, but I'm having a problem.

I downloaded Xcode 4.6.2 from the Mac App Store. After I installed the app, I clicked on the icon in the Launchpad and it just opened and ask me to install device support, so I clicked install. It asked for my password, which I entered, and it threw an error:

> **An unknown error occurred.**
>
> See the install log for more details.

I looked for this problem and I found that I can go to Xcode icon, click on the option and click on "Show Package Contents" and than on Contents->Resources->Packages, than I click "MobileDevice.pkg", and again I entered my password, and nothing happened.

How can I get Xcode to work?

Comment: perhaps this should be moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are you logged as an admin or standard user?

Comment: i think that yes, how can i check it?

Comment: wait... you don't know if the current account you're logged in has administrative privileges?
System prefs -> users

Comment: i checked it and it's ok i loged in with admin user